# Multithreaded access to singleton class

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around accessing a singleton class with multiple threads.

This article has given me a nice starting point to get my singleton thread safe: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

My singleton class is supposed to treat a group of files as a single unity of data, but process them in a parallel fashion.

I store information of each file in a dictionary and return to the calling thread a unique key (which will be created using a DateTime and a random number) so that each thread can later refer to its own file.

```
public string AddFileForProcessing(FileForProcessing file)
{
    var id = CreateUniqueFileId();
    var resultFile = CreateResultFileFor(file);
    //These collections are written here and only read elsewhere
    _files.Add(id, file); 
    _results.Add(id, resultFile)
    return id;
}
```

Then later threads call methods passing this id.

```
public void WriteProcessResultToProperFile(string id, string[] processingResult)
{
   //locate the proper file in dictionary using id and then write information...
    File.AppendAllLines(_results[key].FileName, processingResult);
}
```

Those methods will be accessed inside a class that:

a) Responds to a FileWatcher's Created event and creates threads that call AddFileForProcessing:

```
public void ProcessIncomingFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = ((FileProcessingEventArg)e).File;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    item =>
    {
        ProcessFile(file);
    });
}
```

b) Inside ProcessFile, I add the file to the dictionary and start processing.

```
private void ProcessFile(FileForProcessing file)
{
    var key = filesManager.AddFileForProcessing(file);
    var records = filesManager.GetRecordsCollection(key);

    for (var i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
    {
        //Do my processing here
        filesManager.WriteProcessResultToProperFile(key, processingResult);
    }
}
```

Now I don't get what happens when two threads call these methods, given they're both using the same instance.

Each thread will call AddFileForProcessing and WriteProcessResultToProperFile with a different parameter. Does that make them two different calls?

Since it will operate on a file that will be uniquely identified by the id that belongs to a single thread (i.e.. no file will suffer from multiple accesses), can I leave this method as is or do I still have to "lock" my method?

Comment: What is the instance data that this method is using?

Comment: If `_files` is not a thred-safe collection, you'll have to use locking around it.

Comment: The key is, how are you ensuring "Each thread will call with a **different** parameter." 1. Is `_files` populated by a single thread, or multiple threads? 2. Is `_files` only populated **before** threads which do the processing are kicked off? 3. How do you ensure that each processing thread picks a unique id from `_files`. Can you please share for all these 3 scenarios as well?

Comment: "I store information of each file in a dictionary and return to the calling thread a unique key so that each thread can later refer to its own file." during an initialization process in the thread that the singleton class instance is in?

Comment: in other words.. will the collection of files change at runtime?

Comment: I am sorry, I missed a key word in my earlier comment.. Can you please share **code** for all these 3 scenarios as well? Without explicit code, it is not practical to answer if your current approach is thread safe (consider CodeReview).. Otherwise, the question how to ensure thread safety, is in general too broad. and even with specific scenario, but lacking details, is likely to miss something critical or be answered in wrong way.

Comment: I edited the post to include more code and information.
From the questions **Vikas Gupta** and **BartoszKP** asked I guess I need to lock the access to `AddFileForProcessing` since it changes my dictionary, but I can leave `WriteProcessResultToProperFile` as is, since it only reads the dictionary to access a single file per thread, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you only read from the shared dictionary all should be fine. And you can process the files in parallel as long as they are different files, as you correctly mention.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) explains:

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

So, you can't do anything in parallel if anyone can call `AddFileForProcessing` (without lock). But with calls only to `WriteProcessResultToProperFile`, it will be fine. This implies that if you want to call `AddFileForProcessing` in parallel, then you need locks in **both** methods (in fact: all parts of code that will touch this dictionary).